# converting preformatted text to chararray

Tags: javascript, regex, arrays

Here is

```
Enter Your Name  :xyz
Enter Your Age   :abc
```

I want this preformatted text to be converted into charArray.

I am trying to implement it by converting

```
var something;
var pre=document.getElementsByTagName("pre")[0]; 
pre.innerHTML.split(something);
```

var **something** is supposed to be some regexp.

Here are the requirements for regexp:

1) Preserve all white spaces including multiple spaces where ever present(ie. seperate index of each white space in array)

2) Preserve newline character

Please provide answer in pure javascript .I would be really grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**RegEx :**

```
(.)|(\n)
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/jY3oN1/1)

**Code**

```
pre.innerHTML.match(/(.)|(\n)/g);

//output
["E", "n", "t", "e", "r", " ", "Y", "o", "u", "r", " ", "N", "a", "m", "e", " ", " ", ":", "x", "y", "z", "
", "E", "n", "t", "e", "r", " ", "Y", "o", "u", "r", " ", "A", "g", "e", " ", " ", " ", ":", "a", "b", "c"]
```

there is no way to represnet `\n` as `"\n"`.The 21st element is a `\n`. Thats why the output is a two-line output. if you want to search ad replace `"\n"` use `indexOf("\n")` and replace it with `"\\n"`

**eg:**

```
while(k.indexOf('\n')!= -1) {
        k[k.indexOf('\n')] = "\\n"
}

//output    
    ["E", "n", "t", "e", "r", " ", "Y", "o", "u", "r", " ", "N", "a", "m", "e", " ", " ", ":", "x", "y", "z", "\n", "E", "n", "t", "e", "r", " ", "Y", "o", "u", "r", " ", "A", "g", "e", " ", " ", " ", ":", "a", "b", "c"]
```

**One more alternative using RegEx: though for me its a kind of cludge**

```
var charArr = []
k=$('#regex_string').val().replace(/(.)|(\n)/g, function(a,b) {
    if(a == "\n") {
        charArr.push("\\n")
        return "\\n"
    } else {
        charArr.push(a)
        return a
    }
})
console.log(charArr)
```

Comment: I want \n to be an item in array

Comment: @user2653926, there is no way to represnet \n as '\n'.The 21st element is a \n. Thats why the output is a two-line output. if you want to serch ad replace "\n" use indexOf("\n") and replace it with "\\n"

Comment: @user2653926, updated answer again and that's enough from me for now or explain you problem completely.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript strings are considered char array by default.

```
var x = "this is a string";
```

So you can do:

```
var l = x.length; //get string length
var c = x[l - 1]; // last char of x
```

For numbers you call toString:

```
 var y = 1234;
 var x = y.toString ();
```

Comment: Buddy it helps me preserves the multiple white spaces but not the \n char

Comment: Buddy this fiddle demonstrates that you are wrong: jsfiddle.net/jT8SR/ or maybe your requirements are still not clear.